# Golang error "invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference", Why this happens?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        http.HandleFunc("/cookie", cookie)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // do ...
}

func cookie(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        cd, _ := r.Cookie("hello")

        if cd.Value == "username" {
               // do ...
        }
}
```

if run:

> $ go run main.go

no problem server is work, but in firfox when inserting "/cookie" path the problem occurs.

Error:

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs, as the error message says, when you try to dereference (use) `nil`. Without knowing which line the error was reported on, I would have to guess it's here:

```
    cd, _ := r.Cookie("hello")

    if cd.Value == "username" {  // <-- This line
           // do ...
    }
```

Because you're discarding the error from `r.Cookie()` instead of checking the error, so you don't know that the cookie `hello` doesn't exist, meaning `cd` is `nil`. So when you try to use `cd.Value`, you're dereferencing a nil pointer, causing the panic you're seeing.